# When two rows have equal column value, select row based on second column

Tags: mysql, sql

Imagine that you have such a table schema:

```
+-------------+--------+
|    jobs     | t_jobs |
+-------------+--------+
| id          | id     |
| category_id | job_id | t_jobs.job_id = jobs.id
|             | locale |
|             | status |
+-------------+--------+
```

In app fallback locale is set to 'pl'. App loads data for currently set locale, but if there is no data in this locale, it should load data from fallback locale ('pl').

Now you have 3 situations:

1) t_jobs.locale = "en" and t_jobs.status = "published" and rows as follows:

```
+----------------------------------+
|               t_jobs             |
+----+--------+--------+-----------+
| id | job_id | locale |  status   |
+----+--------+--------+-----------+
|  1 |      1 | pl     | published |
|  2 |      1 | en     | published |
|  3 |      2 | pl     | published |
+----+--------+--------+-----------+
```

result should be:

```
+----+--------+--------+-----------+
| id | job_id | locale |  status   |
+----+--------+--------+-----------+
|  2 |      1 | en     | published |
|  3 |      2 | pl     | published |
+----+--------+--------+-----------+
```

2) t_jobs.locale = "en" and t_jobs.status = "published" and rows as follows:

```
+----------------------------------+
|               t_jobs             |
+----+--------+--------+-----------+
| id | job_id | locale |  status   |
+----+--------+--------+-----------+
|  1 |      1 | pl     | published |
|  2 |      1 | en     | hidden    |
|  3 |      2 | pl     | published |
+----+--------+--------+-----------+
```

result should be:

```
+----------------------------------+
|               result             |
+----+--------+--------+-----------+
| id | job_id | locale |  status   |
+----+--------+--------+-----------+
|  3 |      2 | pl     | published |
+----+--------+--------+-----------+
```

3) t_jobs.locale = "en" and t_jobs.status = "published" and rows as follows:

```
+----------------------------------+
|               t_jobs             |
+----+--------+--------+-----------+
| id | job_id | locale |  status   |
+----+--------+--------+-----------+
|  1 |      1 | pl     | published |
|  2 |      1 | en     | hidden    |
|  3 |      2 | pl     | hidden    |
+----+--------+--------+-----------+
```

result should be:

```
+----------------------------------+
|               result             |
+----+--------+--------+-----------+
|             0 records            |
+----------------------------------+
```

Dream plan is to select rows in current locale ("en") that are matching search criteria and

IF we have two rows with same t_jobs.job_id, then we should select where t_jobs.locale = "en" (translated)
ELSE we have one row with same t_jobs.job_id, then we should select where t_jobs.locale = "pl" (fallback)

Is there any way to achieve such result? I've been trying for a whole day some mysql magic but still with no luck. Every try returns only fallback versions or only translated rows.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a subquery from `t_jobs` where you group by job. With `max(locale = 'en')` you can create a flag, that indicates whether a job has an English locale. Use `HAVING NOT max(status <> 'published')` to filter for jobs that have one status not equal to published. Then join `t_jobs` on the job and the locale. If the flag indicates, that there is an English locale choose the English one otherwise the Polish. Use a `CASE` to do that.

```
SELECT t2.*
       FROM (SELECT t1.job_id,
                    max(locale = 'en') has_locale
                    FROM t_jobs t1
                    GROUP BY t1.job_id
                    HAVING NOT max(status <> 'published')) x
            INNER JOIN t_jobs t2
                       ON t2.job_id = x.job_id
                          AND t2.locale = CASE
                                            WHEN x.has_locale THEN
                                              'en'
                                            ELSE
                                              'pl'
                                          END;
```

You should however consider to move the status in the `jobs` table, as it seems once one row for the job in `t_jobs` is hidden the job is hidden as a whole.

Comment: That's exactly what I've expected it to do - thank you very much! And now I think how should I add categories to it. Consider that table schema is the same as for jobs, but category_id is now parent_id, and parent may have parent_id and so on. I know I should reuse your query, but it seems to be very inefficient. Is there any proper way to do this? Maybe I should leave your sql and move category visibility check to backend in my app?